# New Raspberry Pi won't boot Raspbian on brand new MicroSD card

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie

Good day all,

I am new to the Raspberry Pi. I have just purchased a Raspberry pi 3. I downloaded the Raspbian Jessie OS and installed it on a brand new 32GB Kingston microSD card. On booting I get a kernel panic message (I am appending an image of the output as it means little to me).

Just in case it might be a corrupted image, I re-downloaded and installed on a brand new SD card (as in bought new the very day) of the same model. I get the same error message.

I am not sure which of the codes shown are actually relevant for information.
The string ends with

I would appreciate any guidance into getting this thing to work.

Best regards,

JAIS

[image: Image shows a kernel panic which ends with not syncing]

Comment: How are you powering the Pi ? Recommended power supply is 5V, 2.5A+. Anything less might make it unstable depending on the peripherals connected.

Comment: Are the SD cards class 10? Also, have you tried using a different SD reader/writer? Or if using an adapter use a different adapter if possible of course. But I had similar issues with an older SD card but got it work with a class 10 Samsung SD card is why I ask.

Answer (score 3):

Have you done the following things?

- Formatted the SD-card before you used it (this is important even when you buy a new one)
- Installed Noobs (lite or normal) on the SD card before you installed Raspbian
- Check if you have got a power supply with 5V and 2.5A+
- Boot the Raspberri Pi with all USB devices removed
- If none of the above worked, look at the SD card on a PC and see if there is a file called config.txt in the FAT32 (first and possibly only readable partition). If there is, rename it to config.whatever_floats_your_boat (not literally).

I hope this helped to fix your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Uncommenting `safe hdmi=1` within `/boot/config.txt` solved the issue.

Comment: But is this really a solution, or rather a workaround?